# Recursive function only works for first level of array

Tags: php, recursion

I wrote a recursive function which relies on `echo` to work, and it works perfectly. But, to challenge myself, I wanted to make it return an array of processed values instead of echoing the values directly.

```
printAll(
    json_decode('[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":3}]}]},{"id":4}]', true)
);

function printAll($a, $level = '', $values = []) {
    foreach($a as $v) {
        $values[] = $value = "{$level}{$v['id']}";
        if(!empty($v['children'])) {
            return printAll($v['children'], "{$value}.", $values);
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

But I'm getting unexpected results. This function currently returns an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1.2
    [2] => 1.5
    [3] => 1.5.3
)
```

But in this case, I'm expecting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1.2
    [2] => 1.5
    [3] => 1.5.3
    [4] => 4
)
```

It looks like my recursive function only processes the very first value of `$data` and all of it's children, but never the rest of `$data`. I'm assuming this is because I am using `return` which ends the loop.

My question is, how can I make my `printAll()` function process the entire set of data, without overly complicating the function?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: i think you must add seconde parameter (true) in the `json_decode`, to avoid `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` **error**

Comment: This looks like a wonderful exercise for test-driven development :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that as you have

```
return printAll($v['children'], "{$value}.", $values);
```

part of the way through, this will ignore any further items in subsequent elements.

A quick fix would be to just add the new values into the current values and have the 1 return at the end of the routine...

```
$values += printAll($v['children'], "{$value}.", $values);
```

Comment: If you return at the first item that has any sub items, you will never process the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `return printAll(...)` and add the value to the variable. Otherwise it will stop in the first value that has a `'children'`

```
<?php

function printAll($a, $level = '', $values = []) {
    foreach($a as $v) {
        $values[] = $value = "{$level}{$v['id']}";
        if(!empty($v['children'])) {
            //Just remove this return and add to the variable you already have.
            $values = printAll($v['children'], "{$value}.", $values);
        }
    }
    return $values;
}

$a = json_decode('[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":3}]}]},{"id":4}]',true);
var_dump(printAll($a));
```